# How can get username of post from Instagram Graph API's hashtag recent post

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I tried to get recent posts of an Instagram hashtag like the following document.
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media`

The username of posts isn't included in the response. So I tried using the following api to get post's information to get username, but it didn't work.
Error code 100, sub error code 33 was returned.
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media`

```
{
    "error": {
        "message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17842922015870032' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api",
        "type":"GraphMethodException",
        "code":100,
        "error_subcode":33,
        "fbtrace_id":"ArmZGxqqGmKK_EZr4vqqODv"
   }
}
```

How can I resolve this or have any other way to get username of Instagram post?

Comment: helpful will be, if you show error as text...

Comment: as per this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/error-codes/ it says: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID OBJECT_ID does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation"

Comment: @A.Herlas Yes. But all of media cannot get information. And I have ever used a third party web app can get username from hashtag search. So I think have a way to get username from recent hashtag media.